# When I insert data into database, it is not inserting date format in C#

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, date

I change data table column date format (yyy-mm-dd) when I insert that changed format of data into the database, the column is not showing changed format (yyy-mm-dd) of type, it shows default format (dd-mm-yyy).

How can I insert changed format (yyy-mm-dd) of date column into the database?

```
DataTable dtdate = Exceldt.Copy();

for (int i = 0; i < dtdate.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string yymmdd = Convert.ToDateTime(dtdate.Rows[i]["Month"]).ToString("yyy-MM-dd");
    dtdate.Rows[i]["Month"] = yymmdd;
}

dtdate.AcceptChanges();

// Inserting
SqlBulkCopy objbulk = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
objbulk.DestinationTableName = "tablname";
// mapping the columns 
objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("ID", "MID");
objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Month", "Date");//source,destination

con.Open();
objbulk.WriteToServer(dtdate);
con.Close();
```

Comment: ` it shows default format` - what is *it*?

Comment: Hi ,I mentioned in question default format  `dd-mm-yyy`

Comment: But where the date in bad format is shown, in your ASP.NET page or in SQL Server Management Studio or what is the it that shows the date.

Comment: Your problem is that the `Date` column is probably of type `DateTime` and the varchar gets converted to DateTime.

Comment: `DATE` or `DATETIME` in SQL Server **have no format** associated with them - they are stored as **binary bytes**. The formatting only comes into play when you select from the table - and it's controlled by SQL Server. Therefore, you **cannot** insert a date or date&time *in a given format* - if you insert a date/time, it's just some binary bytes that get stored - no matter in what *format* you insert them ......